# Should you refrain from putting ash on your forehead if your wedding coincides with Ash Wednesday?

Tags: halacha, wedding, christianity, non-jewish-holidays, fire-burning

Some brides/grooms have a custom to put ash on the forehead at their wedding as a remembrance for the destruction of the temple. Is there any halachic discussion about avoiding this practice if the wedding date coincides with [Ash Wednesday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_Wednesday)?

Comment: Moreover, there is a custom to get married on Wednesday specifically. http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%90

Comment: This calls to mind another question -- do we change our practice if, afterwards, the non-Jewish world institutes a similar practice? My superficial research indicates that the Catholic practice of ashes dates to the 10th century while ashes on a chatan is from bava batra 60b

Comment: If the Seder night is on Easter Sunday should one not eat eggs?